# D3.js Tree - Text not appearing insides nodes, in firefox or edge

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have this tree structure visualization and it loads in chrome, firefox, and edge, however, it only loads the text inside the nodes on chrome.

Here is a picture of what it looks like on chrome.

[image]

And here is what it looks like on firefox and edge.

[image]

Is there some way to make it show, I assume it's just compatibility issues with D3.js and the browser standards. So is there anything i can add or change to make it appear?

[Here is the link to the original code.](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083)

Comment: a fiddle would help

Comment: added a jsfiddle

Comment: I see the text elements in firefox.

Comment: the version that i am working on, a person has amended it to make it look different, and the code is huge to submit here, which is why i added the original. should i add here anyways?

Comment: it would help but if it is huge and difficult wait a bit maybe someone has come up with a hint

Comment: okay i added the actual code snippets

Comment: Create a [mcve] or this won't go anywhere. There are some font-size=0 values in there but presumably Chrome would pick those up too.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. The first instance of font-size=0, i changed the value to 10, and it appeared. It's strange because that case is for a certain type of node, but I guess it targets all types of nodes regardless. Not sure how Chrome managed to display it though.

Comment: this has nothing to do with servicenow, remove the tag please